# Sass with XAMPP result error

Tags: sass, xampp

I have installed SASS using Ruby command prompt with SASS Gem command. It installed successfully. While I try to use my scss directory under XAMPP its end up with the following error:

```
C:\Users\Deb>sass --watch app/sass:../xampp/htdocs/weplaybyear/skin/frontend/weplaybyear/default/scss
Sass is watching for changes. Press Ctrl-C to stop.
  directory ../xampp/htdocs/weplaybyear/skin/frontend/weplaybyear/default
Errno::EACCES: Permission denied @ dir_s_mkdir - ../xampp
  Use --trace for backtrace.
```

What I want to achieve is I have scss directory under `xampp/htdocs/weplaybyear/skin/frontend/weplaybyear/default/scss` and output css into `xampp/htdocs/weplaybyear/skin/frontend/weplaybyear/default/css`

Comment: The path specified in your command doesn't agree with the path you claim the files are in.  When you run the `sass` command, all paths should be relative to the current working directory.  If I understand the path structure, you're telling sass to compile the files in `C:\Users\Deb\app\sass` and place them into `C:\Users\xamp\htdocs\weplaybyear\skin\frontend\weplaybyear\default\css`.  Is this correct?

Comment: Hi cimmanon, thanks for your reply. I have a direcotry with all scss files and other css. Want to edit the scss files so it will get rendered into css files automatically. Thanks

Comment: That doesn't answer my question.  Which set of paths is correct?  The ones you are using in the command?

Comment: this is my scss files path:/xampp/htdocs/weplaybyear/skin/frontend/weplaybyear/default/scss and this is my css: /xampp/htdocs/weplaybyear/skin/frontend/weplaybyear/default

Hope that is what you asking for.

Comment: Then it should be something like: `C:\xampp\htdocs\weplaybyear\skin\frontend\weplaybyear\>sass --watch default/scss:default/css` this will convert all scss in default/scss in css to the default/css folder. Notice your current commandline dir(!). Another error I see is permission denied, perhaps start xampp and your command prompt as administrator.